# Share data between two child components(sibling components) through a service in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Child Component 1**
I am having a date picker field which will be used as a filter to fetch the results and display it in *Child Component 2*.   Meanwhile, I have created a service and share data from Child Component 1 to that service.

**Child Component 2**
I am able to subscribe to the data on `ngOnInit()` method.

**My expectation**:
But since this date picker changes often to filter the results, I want to subscribe to it in *Child Component 2* outside `ngOnInit()` i.e I want to subscribe to real-time data.

***Note***: No code change has been made in the parent component

**Child Component 1.ts**

```
shareDate(fromDateEvent){
    const fromDate = fromDateEvent.target.value;
    this.sharedService.updateFilterDate(fromDate);
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
private filterDate = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
get filterDate$(): Observable<string> {
        return this.filterDate.asObservable();
}
updateFilterDate(fromDate: string): void{
      this.filterDate.next(fromDate);
}
```

**Child Component 2**

```
this.sharedService.updateFilterDate.subscribe(dateValue => this.fromDate = dateValue);
```

Comment: from the code you supplied, your Component 2 should be subscribing to `filterDate$` in your service not `updateFilterDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In child component 2 make this change

`this.sharedService.filterDate$().subscribe(dateValue => this.fromDate = dateValue);`

You have to subscribe to the **observable** to get the stream of data.